# My openshift v3 says "Storage quota limit has been reached"

Tags: mysql, openshift

I got a project at Openshift v2 that includes a mysql.
I migrated it to Openshift v3 (free), and all seems to be fine.
But in the webconsole it says:

> Storage quota limit has been reached. You will not be able to create any new storage.

But when I run a `size_check_select`:

```
SELECT table_schema "DB Name"
       , Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
  FROM information_schema.tables 
 GROUP BY table_schema;
```

```
+--------------------+---------------+
| DB Name            | DB Size in MB |
+--------------------+---------------+
| information_schema |           0.2 |
| jbossas            |          10.3 |
| mysql              |           0.8 |
| performance_schema |           0.0 |
| sys                |           0.0 |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

It looks like I just use below 11MB how come I get this warning? Is something eating memory? Am I in trouble?

Answer (score 1):

It is not talking about the amount of space you have used on the volume, but how many storage volumes you have claimed.

Run:

```
oc get pvc
```

or look under *Storage* in the web console. It likely shows you have 1 persistent volume claims, which in starter tier is all you are allowed. Thus it is warning you that you are at your limit.

You can look under *Resources->Quota* to see how much of the provided resources you have used and how much is still available.

Comment: Note: Only 1 persistent volume claim is allowed on the OpenShift Online Starter tier, allowing you to have a single 1 GiB persistent storage volume.